# Infinite Loop between WebApp and AAD Authentication after introducing Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway, azure-authentication

We were trying to enable AppGateway on one of our WebApplication hosted on AppService which use OpenIDConnect to Auth the request against Azure AD using Code with PKCE flow.

Since our *.azurewebsite.net url is going to be private, we had to update the "Redirect URI" in AAD and in the Web.config to rout the request back to AppGateway after Authentication and then with the Authenticated Payload the request should hit the Backend Pool which has the AppService.

But, every time we try this configuration we ended up being in an Endless Loop between
AppGateway --> AppService(BackendPool) --> Authentication page --> AppGateWay -->...

Answer (score 0):

•   You are encountering the endless loop when setting up the application gateway in front of your app service because the **reply URLs** set for the app service on the application gateway may not be correctly configured due to which even after redirecting to the configured reply URLs, you are not able to go to the set app service page after authentication. For this purpose, kindly go to the **‘Authentication/Authorization’** blade on your app service, click on the **“Azure Active Directory”** option. In there, click on **“Manage Application”**. This will take you to the Azure Active Directory configuration. In that, select the **‘Express’ mode**, and select the option for **‘Manage Application’**, and in that select “Reply URLs” in the “Settings” blade. This will open the various reply URLs that the application is able to use to send an authenticated user back to your application.

•   If you configured your custom domain before setting up Azure Active Directory authentication, both your **‘*.azurewebsites.net’** and **custom domain URLs** should be configured for the reply URLs. If your custom domain is not there, be sure to set up the reply URL as **‘https:///.auth/login/aad/callback’**. Once the said has been set up correctly as specified, you should be able to authenticate using either the custom domain or the *.azurewebsites.net hostname to ensure you can sign in.

•   Ensure that you **change your custom domain** from pointing to the App Service to pointing to the Application Gateway's **public IP or DNS name**. This change is made in your DNS registrar.

Finally, I would suggest you to please refer and go through these below documentation links for more details on configuring the app service for custom DNS/default domain and AAD authentication: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=customdomain%2Cazure-portal#configure-a-web-app-behind-an-existing-application-gateway

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/waws/setting-up-application-gateway-with-an-app-service-that-uses-azure-active-directory-authentication#setting-up-the-application-gateway

Comment: We have tried the above setup but again it ended up on the same scenario - Looping.

Also, Authentication on AppService is not set through 'Authentication/Authorization’ blade on the app service page, instead we use "OpenIDConnect" to Authorize our request against Azure AD using "Code with PKCE flow".

Comment: Have you checked your custom domain setup as discussed above in the answer?? It might help you with the infinite loop issue or please check the TTL set for your custom domain whether it is correct or not.